# libSQLite.Interop not found Mac OS | M1

Tags: .net, apple-m1, .net-6.0, sqlite-net

I am using dotnet 6 on a M1 Pro, and am struggling to use the SQLite-Package.

`System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies.`

This is the error that is thrown, whenever I try to run the application. Building however works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround to [sqlite not yet targeting arm64](https://sqlite.org/forum/info/c785cbb6d537914c7e078e7cb923238e5f517ea77b13177a59216f50ef88b2a7), you can use the .net 6 x64 architecture.

- Install .net 6 x64 from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.302-macos-x64-installer).
- Configure your IDE (or terminal) to use .net x64.  This will vary by IDE, but in Rider:

  - Press `CMD ,` to open preferences
  - Navigate to "Toolset and build" section
  - Change the .NET CLI executable path to `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet`

[image]

Comment: This is what solved it for me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

I managed to fix this issue by building both the Interop.dll file and the dotnet library file on my M1 macbook from source. Only building the Interop.dll results in an EntrypointNotFoundException. To build the library, download the source code from [the SQLite website](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), as of writing this is the file `sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.115.5.zip`. Extract it and run the file `Setup/compile-interop-assembly-release.sh`. To build the Library, run `dotnet build -c Release` in the `System.Data.SQLite` directory. Your interop file will be in `bin/2013/Release/bin`. I symlinked it to `/usr/local/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll`, but you can also copy it into your project directory as `libSQLite.Interop.dll`. Now add a reference to `bin/NetStandard21/ReleaseNetStandard21/bin/netstandard2.1/System.Data.SQLite.dll` into your project and it should run fine.

Update:
It also runs fine using the outdated version `1.0.115` directly from NuGet as of writing.

Comment: I also had to modify the `compile-interop-assembly-release.sh` with ` gccflags="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"` instead of just ` gccflags="-arch x86_64"`

Anyways, thanks a lot for your answer, could not find any solutions to this :)

Comment: These steps worked great for me on 1.0.116 on a linux arm64 ubuntu docker container running on an M1 mac.  A few notes: In the `System.Data.SQLite` dir, I had to run `dotnet build -c Release System.Data.SQLite.NetStandard21.csproj` (i.e., specifying the project); I ran the following to install the interop lib: `sudo cp ./sqlite-source/bin/2013/Release/bin/SQLite.Interop.dll /usr/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll`; I had to remove the `ProjectReference` to `System.Data.SQLite.Core` in my project, as well as adding the Reference to the compiled `System.Data.SQLite.dll`.

Comment: Could someone who managed to compile for arm64 share the resulting dlls? @teocomi?